# Bootstrap datetimepicker: set view only date, day not preselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [this bootstrap datetime picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewdate).
Here's my code:

```
    var dp = $('#datetimepicker')
        .datetimepicker({
            viewDate: setViewDate(),
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            maxDate: moment(currentDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
            minDate: moment(currentDate).subtract(200, 'years')
        });

    function setViewDate (){
        if (!$('#datetimepicker').find('input').val()) { 
            return moment(new Date()).subtract(30, 'years'); }
        else { return false; }
}
```

How the above works is if the datetimepicker input doesn't have any value, when we open the picker, the date in the picker (and not the actual input date) should be today - 30 years.

This works fine except the day in the picker is not selected, see below:

[image]

Q: How can I preselect the day also in the picker? (not the actual input value)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting date like this:

```
$("#datePicker")
 .datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   autoclose: true
  });

$("#datePicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

So, if you want other date, you can make it as `new Date("October 13, 2014)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the date in the datepicker as well

```
$('#datetimepicker').datepicker('update', moment(new Date()).subtract(30, 'years'));
```

Comment: I'm actually using the datetimepicker plugin, not the datepicker one ...

Comment: I went through the link that you have given.
`$("#datetimepicker").data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(moment(new Date()).subtract(30, 'years'));` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I took  a quick look at the reference doc , I think you should use "defaultViewDate" option [defaultviewdate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate)

Comment: that does not work, I'm using https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewdate

Comment: what about "useCurrent" ? option